# Dart: Order a list of timestamps by time only

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of timestamps that I am trying to order by the time only and then display as a time of day. For example the following list:

```
List _TimesToOrder = [1616360400, 1624262400, 1624258800, 1621587600]
```

I want to convert to Text I can display in the following order:

7:00AM, 8:00AM, 9:00AM, 9:00PM - and ignore the date in the timestamp.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following statements to cast the timestamps into `DateTime` objects in the same day but keep the hours, minutes and seconds only.

```
final List<int> timesToReorder = [1616360400, 1624262400, 1624258800, 1621587600];
final List<DateTime> dateTimeObjects = timesToReorder.map((int milliseconds) {
  return DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
}).map((DateTime dateTime) {
  return DateTime(2000, 1, 1, dateTime.hour, dateTime.minute, dateTime.second);
}).toList();
```

Then use the following to sort the list:

```
dateTimeObjects.sort((a, b) {
  return a.compareTo(b);
});
```

Finally, format the `Datetime` objects by using `intl` package:
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  var times = [1616360400, 1624262400, 1624258800, 1621587600];
  final h12 = (int h) => h >= 12 ? h - 12 : h;
  final ap = (int h) => h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  final pd = (int x) => x < 10 ? '0$x' : '$x';
  
  times
    ..sort()
    ..forEach((t) {
      var tt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(t);
      print('${pd(h12(tt.hour))}:${pd(tt.minute)}:${pd(tt.second)} ${ap(tt.hour)}');
    });
}
```

Result:

```
11:59:20 AM
01:26:27 PM
02:10:58 PM
02:11:02 PM
```